# Returning the Values from a Dictionary to COM/VBA

Tags: excel, com-interop, vba

We have a number of `Dictionary(Of Integer, whatever)` in our object model. We need to allow VBA (Excel specifically) users to loop over the values. In .net you simply return the`.Values`, can you use that from VBA? I'm never entirely sure what things I can pass over safely.

Comment: Dictionary implements System.Collections.IDictionary.  Which is a [ComVisible] interface type, VBA code can use it directly.  The *whatever* of course needs to be [ComVisible] as well.

Comment: My goal is to return some sort of array/list/etc like object though, the keys are private and should not be visible. I tried simply returning the ValueCollection, would I simply return an IEnumerable or something like that?

Comment: ValueCollection implements System.Collection.ICollection and IEnumerable, directly usable by VBA.  Pick one.